# Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysql_driver::where()

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I just upgraded my version of CodeIgniter... I went through the config files and copied over any values that weren't in my existing configuration but were inside the new config files.  I'm running into an error where Active Record isn't working and I'm unsure why.  I'm trying to debug and trace it back to a problem within the code but am struggling.  Any ideas on what I should do?  My error is

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysql_driver::where() in /scripts/htdocs/smartdox-libraries/smartdox/system/libraries/Session.php on line 201
```

CI's own session class is trying to use this function.

**config/database.php**

```
$active_group = "default";
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = CPOD_DATABASE_SERVER;
$db['default']['username'] = CPOD_DATABASE_USER;
$db['default']['password'] = CPOD_DATABASE_PASSWORD;
$db['default']['database'] = CPOD_DATABASE;
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = "";
$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = "";
$db['default']['char_set'] = "utf8";
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
```

After initial investigation it looks like having a "database" object loaded into CI's library auto load causes a DB object loaded with the `$active_record` value pulling in false.

Comment: What is the active record code that you're using? Are you able to run any other queries using active record? Have you auto loaded the database library?

Comment: Did you check `config/autoload.php` to ensure the db auto load library action? I'm using CI v 2.0.3 and for working with active records I just loaded the `db` library. Don't know what's exactly the problem. I think it's better to share it in CI forums.

Comment: Where are those `CPOD_DATABASE*` constants defined?

Comment: @Catfish No, this is the session library, it's the first thing that tries to use the database class.

Comment: @MahanGM - I did post on the forums.  Link is here: http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/208111/

Comment: @Narf - In another file that's loaded with the config settings.  I was running CI an earlier version of CI so I know the constants and their values are correct.

Comment: Sometimes you get session errors when trying to do other things. Please answer the other questions from my first comment so we have more to go off of.

Comment: Well then, can you put your log level to debug and tell us what it shows?

Comment: @Webnet - You said you've upgraded your version. I don't know what's like the update process of CI but maybe there is a wrong move that you did. Try to make a test project with new CI and make sure you do everything right to work with active records. It's my least opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the datamapper bootstrap to the bottom of your index.php file? This fixed my problem.

See point 9 on the installation page:
http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/installation.html